# Is there a way to do OR in jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

for example, something like...

```
// get everything that is either an input or a select
$container.find(':any(input, select)');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
$container.find('input, select');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`:input`**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector

```
$containder.find(":input")
```

which selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.